# Can't install node js ver 18 on centOS 7.9

Tags: node.js, centos7

when i trying install node js ver 18 on centos it's show me this error

```
Error: Package: 2:nodejs-18.15.0-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit)
Error: Package: 2:nodejs-18.15.0-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit)
Error: Package: 2:nodejs-18.15.0-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
           Requires: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit)
Error: Package: 2:nodejs-18.15.0-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit)
Error: Package: 2:nodejs-18.15.0-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit)
```

i installed gcc but it still give me error

Comment: Can you try this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-a-centos-7-server.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? That link does not address that error although it keeps on showing up among the top results unfortunately

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ran into the same issue on CentOS 7.9. The solution was to install `dnf` and use that to install `nodejs` and `yarn`. Complete set of commands for nodejs + yarn:

Add repos (https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#installation-instructions-1):

```
curl -fsSL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | sudo bash -
curl -sL https://dl.yarnpkg.com/rpm/yarn.repo | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/yarn.repo
```

Install dnf

```
sudo yum install dnf
```

Install node and yarn:

```
sudo dnf install nodejs
sudo dnf install yarn
```

Comment: worked for me too for Enterprise Redhat 7.9. Thank you!

Comment: it's worked for me.thinks.But I have another question, the installation of npm keeps failing, what can I do to install it properly on centos?

Comment: You cannot install Nodejs 18 or higher on Centos 7, since it requiers glibc version of 2.28 and centos 7 has 2.17.

Answer (score 0):

See “Toolchain and Compiler Upgrades” in official doc of release 18, it requires glibs 2.28

[2022-04-19, Version 18.0.0](https://github.com/nodejs/node/releases/tag/v18.0.0)