# centOs 7 instal nodejs 18

Tags: node.js, centos7

```
Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: nsolid conflicts with 2:nodejs-18.19.1-1nodesource.x86_64
Error: Package: 2:nodejs-18.19.1-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource-nodejs)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit)
Error: Package: 2:nodejs-18.19.1-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource-nodejs)
           Requires: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit)
Error: Package: 2:nodejs-18.19.1-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource-nodejs)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit)
Error: Package: 2:nodejs-18.19.1-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource-nodejs)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit)
Error: Package: 2:nodejs-18.19.1-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource-nodejs)
           Requires: glibc >= 2.28
           Installed: glibc-2.17-292.el7.x86_64 (@base)
               glibc = 2.17-292.el7
           Available: glibc-2.17-317.el7.i686 (base)
               glibc = 2.17-317.el7
           Available: glibc-2.17-322.el7_9.i686 (updates)
               glibc = 2.17-322.el7_9
           Available: glibc-2.17-323.el7_9.i686 (updates)
               glibc = 2.17-323.el7_9
           Available: glibc-2.17-324.el7_9.i686 (updates)
               glibc = 2.17-324.el7_9
           Available: glibc-2.17-325.el7_9.i686 (updates)
               glibc = 2.17-325.el7_9
           Available: glibc-2.17-326.el7_9.i686 (updates)
               glibc = 2.17-326.el7_9
Error: Package: 2:nodejs-18.19.1-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource-nodejs)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit)
```

I user this [Can't install node js ver 18 on centOS 7.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75854828/cant-install-node-js-ver-18-on-centos-7-9)

than tips  :
nodejs]# dnf install nodejs
Segmentation fault (core dumped)